# How do I debug FIELD_DISCARDED_TYPE_CONVERSION_FAILED?

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

My `pig` script produces this warning:

> WARN 
>   org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher
>   - Encountered Warning FIELD_DISCARDED_TYPE_CONVERSION_FAILED 14 time(s).

1. Is there a way to make it more informative? E.g., what is the alias/record/column which triggered it?
2. How do I debug it?

Comment: Wow, 7 years and no proper answer, is there really no way to know which line and field was discarded?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this helps someone. I got the same error when I was loading in "chararray" data as "long". Just check your schemas.